# Java modify Class element on arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

I have two arraylist like this

```
ArrayList<Paragens> paragens = new ArrayList<Paragens>();
ArrayList<Rotas> rotas = new ArrayList<Rotas>();
```

Paragens is a class and the constructor is

```
public Paragens(String nomeParagem) {
    this.nomeParagem = nomeParagem;
    this.existeNaRota = new String[]{"","","","","","","","","","","","","",
    "","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",
    "","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",
    "","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""};
    this.id = contadorParagens++;
}
```

I have another class. The Rotas class.

```
public Rotas(String nomeRota, Paragens[] nomeParagens) {
    this.nomeRota = nomeRota;
    this.nomeParagens = nomeParagens;
    this.id = contadorRotas++;
}
```

So there are `Paragens` (each one with a name[`nomeParagem`], an id[`contadorParagens`] and the rotas in wich they exist [`existeNaRota`].

First, the user inputs `Paragens` witch are only created with `nomeParagem`(it's name) and its `id`. Since Rotas are added latter, `existeNaRota` it's empty.

Each `Paragem` is then added to `paragens` arraylist

When user adds an `Rotas` he inputs `Rota` name and then the list of `Paragens` that exist on that `Rotas`. `Rotas are finally added to`rotas` arraylist.

What I want to do is, when user insert `Paragens` that exists on one `Rotas`, `existeNaRota` is them populated with the `Rotas` that `Paragem`exists.

Example.

User inputs some names and then `Paragens` are created like this:

```
paragem = new Paragens("London");
paragens.add(paragem);
paragem = new Paragens("Manchester");
paragens.add(paragem);
paragem = new Paragens("Chelsea");
paragens.add(paragem);
```

Now user will input `Rotas` like this:

```
estacoes[0] = "Chelsea";
estacoes[1] = "London";
rota = new Rotas("Route A", estacoes);
rotas.add(rota);
```

Now, since there is a `Rota` I want to go back to `Paragens` and put the name on `existeNaRota`.

On `Paragens` I have this set method

```
public void setExisteNaRota(String existeNaRota, int indice) {
    this.existeNaRota[indice] = existeNaRota;
    indice++;
}
```

Is it possible to access the `paragens` arraylist, find the "Chelsea" `Paragem` and add "Rota A" to the first position of `existeNaRota`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, consider using a `List` in `Paragens' instead of an array since you are going to be adding elements to it. This will allow for adding (potentially to the head of the list) without moving elements in the array.

Second, provide a method in `Paragens` like `addRota(Rota r)` that adds the `Rota` to the `List` of `Rotas` in the `Paragens`.

```
class Paragens{
   List<Rota> existEnRota = new ArrayList<Rota>();


   public void addRota(Rota r){
       existEnRota.add(0, r);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a Map.

```
Map<String, Paragens> paragens = new HashMap<String, Paragens>();
paragens.put("London", new Paragens("London");
paragens.put("Chelsea", new Paragens("Chelsea");
paragens.put("Manchester", new Paragens("Manchester");
estacoes[0] = "Chelsea";
estacoes[1] = "London";
Rotas rota = new Rotas("Route A", estacoes);
rotas.add(rota);
Paragens p = paragens.get(estacoes[0]);
if (p != null) {
    p.addRota(rota);
}
p = paragens.get(estacoes[1]);
if (p != null) {
    p.addRota(rota);
}
```

Assuming here addRota adds to list of rotas in paragens, like so:

```
public class Paragens {
    List<Rotas> existeNaRota = new ArrayList<Rotas>();
    public void addRota(Rotas r) {
        existeNaRota.add(r);
    }
}
```

along with other things